# How to apply filter at report side in ssrs 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

I have a expression inside a tablix for one of my report column Cases Shipped like this
=IIF(Fields!Current_Product.Value= "Match"," ",Sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value))
This add the cases shipped value of same ditributor item code.
After this statement i want to apply a filter on this column on the report .there is a textbox parameter in which a user enter the number like 10 and the column on report get filtered through this value.

How can i do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to change the Column Group visibility. (You are using column groups, right?) If so, right click on a column group and you can set the visibility by formula. The formula can incorporate a Parameter.

```
=IIF(sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value ) >= Parameters!CasesShipped.Value and (Fields!Stocked.Value = "" OR Fields!Stocked.Value = "Yes" OR Fields!Stocked.Value = "No"), false, true)
```

Comment: That is good thought,but my filter condition is very complex like this.                                                                               (([Cases Shipped]>=@CasesShipped) And Stocked in('','Yes','No')) 
           OR
  ([Cases Shipped]<@CasesShipped And Stocked  not in ('No'))                                                                           This is sql condition and it is working fine ,now i want to apply this condition like expression.Here  [Cases Shipped] is the column that get filtered and Stocked  is another column which value is tested for filteration.

Comment: I have written this                                                    =IIF(sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value )>=Parameters!CasesShipped.Value and Fields!Stocked.Value in ('','Yes','No'),false,true)   but it seems there is problem at in operator.

Comment: Not working in ssrs,after or oprator it gives the red error line .Tooltip saying that there is syntax error                                                                                                                     =IIF(sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value ) >= Parameters!CasesShipped.Value and (Fields!Stocked.Value = '' OR Fields!Stocked.Value = 'Yes' OR Fields!Stocked.Value = 'No'), false, true)

Comment: Hey Jamie it works now that means there is no error now ,thanks.

Comment: Hey I have it on row group not in column group.is it  ok?

Comment: If you are setting the visibility of the row group with this, then the entire group will be hidden when this returns true. I thought you wanted to hide certain columns. No different necessary in the formula, though.

Comment: I have not mentioned anywhere that i want to hide the columns.

Comment: I have not mentioned anywhere that i want to hide the columns.I just want to filter a column based on a complex criteria once the sum has get rerived through =IIF(Fields!Current_Product.Value= "Match"," ",Sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value))

Comment: What does "Filter a column" mean? I took this to mean that you wanted to hide the column when certain values do not match the criteria? What do you want to hide: a column, a field, a row?

Comment: filter means if a user select 10 then it should filter records whcih has the above condition trie.

Comment: I think you are thinking that a record = a row (or group of rows.) SSRS does not have to work like this. A record could be a cell, or a column, or just part of an aggregate. Depending on what you want to show and hide, then you need to filter at different places.  (In your question you said "apply a filter on this column," which I thought meant you wanted to hide a column.)  
Anyway, yes, the visibility formula should work on row groups or column groups just the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4429/discussion-between-vikram-se-and-jamie-f)