# Dataset filtering in a SSRS report - how to hide records with 0s only

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Based on the http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2597/dataset-and-tablix-filtering-in-sql-server-reporting-services/, I created a dataset in a SSRS report which returns results like this:

[image]

I want to hide rows which contain only 0 using the dataset filtering feature, so that the tablix shows something like this:

```
5     178
399   141
0     750 
12    6
0     26
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I used a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838927/how-to-apply-filter-at-report-side-in-ssrs-2008-r2. I set Visibility expression on the Row Group using this formula: =IIF(SUM(Fields!Field1.Value) > 0 OR (SUM(Fields!Field2.Value) > 0), false, true)  and the result was magical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the expression (click the fx button) in your filter to be:

```
=Fields!ColumnA.Value + Fields!ColumnB.Value
```

Operator: >

and Value: 0

Answer (score 2):

Try to add Filters to dataset..Following link will help you..
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255287.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I knew how to add a filter just did not know how to use it properly as the report complained about using aggregates in a filter